# Get Thread Name from inner object method

Tags: c#, multithreading

i know i can get the Thread Name by calling Thread.CurrentThread.Name

but i got a tricky scenario.

i created two thread, each launch a new object (says objA) and run a method.

inside the object (objA) method (objAM), i create another object (says objB) and run a method (objBM).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TESTA a = new TESTA();
        }

    }

    class TESTA
    {
        private Thread t;

        public TESTA()
        {
            t = new Thread(StartThread);
            t.Name = "ABC";
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();

            t = new Thread(StartThread);
            t.Name = "XYZ";
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();

        }

        private void StartThread()
        {
            objA thisA = new objA();
        }
    }

    class objA
    {
        private System.Threading.Timer t1;

        public objA()
        {
            objAM();
            t1 = new Timer(new TimerCallback(testthread), null, 0, 1000);
        }

        private void objAM()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ObjA:" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        }

        private void testthread(object obj)
        {
            objB thisB = new objB();
        }
    }

    class objB
    {
        public objB()
        {
            objBM();
        }

        private void objBM()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ObjB:" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

but the value of Thread.CurrentThread.Name in objB return empty.

How can i get the Thread Name inside objBM?

Comment: The code sample you provided doesn't compile. If you want help, you might consider providing a short complete program that compiles and illustrates the error.

Comment: updated. i am thinking does it related to threading.timer instead of timer.timer is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From description of [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx): The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system.

Thus your `testthread` method executed on unnamed ThreadPool thread. Btw you can verify it by calling `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread`.